# Choose Directory with JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm creating UI for backup and restore database in my J2EE app. I need to allow user to select a directory in his PC hard drive to save database backup.

I can select `sql` file to carry out restoration by this. `<input type="file" accept=".sql">`.

But i'm unable to find a way to select directory to save database backup file. I have google about this and found that there is no any way to select directories with jsp/html file.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons browser will not allow you to select a folder on the users local drive to store files in.

What you can do is set the Content-Disposition header at the moment the file is sent to the client (browser). In that case the browser will show as 'Save as' dialog. With this the user can select the folder to store the files in.

See [this page](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index3.html) on how to set the content disposition header.

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename +"\"");
res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have did as in given url. but file is downloading to the pc without showing `Save as` dialog. What could be the issue ?

Comment: What does the content disposition header look likee when you look at it with for instance firefox? Make sure that you put the file name between quotes in case you have spaces in the file name.

Comment: It downloads the file to default download location. I can't select location to save the file.

Comment: This could be due to the fact that: A) The extension or mimetype is recognized by the browser and it uses the default action (see your screenshot above) or B) you have not set the correct content type to the response. Try setting the content type to application/octet-stream and let the file extension end with .sql. See if that works. For inspiration see http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-to-download-file-from-database